# Parameter sweeps on a HPC cluster

Tags: parallelization, high-performance-clusters

I have a mathematica *.wl file set up, such that there are a couple of parameters defined in the beginning, and, when run, it produces a few outputs. I can run this script on a Slurm-run HPC cluster and everything works fine.

Now to my question: I want to launch this *.wl script several times, each time with slightly different parameters defined in the beginning. And run the same script (with different initial parameters) in parallel. Running this file in parallel is no problem, however, how can I write a sbatch script such that the parameters in the beginning of the *.wl file are changed each time?

Comment: Why not pass them as command line in your slurm script? That can be parsed out on the Mathematica side. This is what I do with my Mathematica jobs on my local neighborhood HPC.

Comment: How would that work explicitly?

Comment: Use `$CommandLine` or whatever. Then when you call stuff in srun you can just supply different args just like calling a python script or similar.

Comment: I use Mathematica's built-in parallelizaton for this (ParallelTable and such). Let me know if you need some guidance on how to set this up on a cluster.

Comment: Some guidance would be fantastic!

Comment: So say, I have a function that takes in some parameter values, and puts out some results. But I have saved that function as a *.wl. Should I then call that function inside the `ParallelTable` each time with `Needs`, or how would one go about this?